# Как сделать кастомную кнопку Facebook Log In чтоб правильно смотрелось?

Tags: java, android

Я погуглил и нашел несколько вариантов как это можно сделать, но ни один мне не подошел... Я думаю, что все дело в том, что с появлением новой библиотеки facebook предыдущие способы теперь не работают...

Последнее из того, что я попробовал и получилось без ошибок это просто задать

```
style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
```

И в стиле я просто указываю нужный мне бэкграунд...

Это единсьвенное, что у меня работает без ошибок, но в таком случае стандартная картинка этой кнопки накладывается поверх моего бэкграунда который я задаю в стилях...

Кто в последнее время кастомизировал эту кнопку подскажите как правильно сделать?

Comment: @pavlofff я не уверен, что мой вопрос об этом же... Вы описали в нем стандартную процедуру, но следуя моему вопросу в нем указано, что я установил стиль и в стиле поставил бэкграунд как у вас и описано, но у меня почему то одна картинка накладывается на другую... То есть я вижу и свой фон который задал и очертания стандартной кнопки которая идет с библиотекой логина... вот такая вот проблема...

Comment: Опишите эти подробности в вопросе, что используете библиотеку и какую, как и что делаете и что не получается.

Comment: @pavlofff так описано же вроде...

Comment: а можно ли вообще менять кнопку FB? они вроде бы запрещают это делать? Или я не прав?

Comment: Не уверен... Так как находил примеры людей на старых версиях где делали кастомизацию... Правда без замены фона... То есть цвет и шрифты соблюдались, просто на кнопке было написано `LogIn` и больше ничего...

Comment: Всегда интересно зачем? сделай свою кнопку, как тебе надо и где тебе надо и ее используй. работает на всех версиях facebook sdk )